# Printer not printing but recognized by computer

Tags: printing

I currently have an hp laserjet 1022 on my ubuntu 14.04. When I tried to print from pdf is said usr/lib/cups/backend/hp not available. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you print from other applications?

Answer (score 0):

The HP website does not list Linux as an available operating system for the HP 1022.  You may be able to use it with some applications but some may give problems like the one you are experiencing with PDF file printing.

If you can print from Libreoffice with the current printer setup, just import it into Libroffice.  The file will be imported as an image file and can only be saved in an image file format, but you will be able to print without the need to invest in a PDF file conversion program like Able2Extract (7 day free trial thru Software Center).